# How can I perform a dragging on a grid, If I use Vis.js for network and D3.js for grid (axis), where the grid is a background element?

Tags: angular, d3.js, drag, vis.js

I'm using D3.js (axis) to plot an elastic grid that can be zoomed and dragged, and it works as expected, except that I'm also using Vis.js to plot a node and edges network, where the network is placed in foreground, and doesn't allow me to drag the grid.
Any solution for that?

Angular component typescript code

```
 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    timer(10)
      .subscribe(() => {
        this._headerHeight = this._window.ref.document.querySelector('.v-modal__header').getBoundingClientRect().height;
        this._footerHeight = this._window.ref.document.querySelector('.v-modal__footer').getBoundingClientRect().height;
        this.initGrid();
        this.initNetwork();
        const storedGraphNetwork: ScanGraph = this._localStorage.get('_dev_graph_network');
        if (storedGraphNetwork) {
          this._nodes = this.getNodesFromGraph(storedGraphNetwork);
          this.network.setData({ nodes: this._nodes });
          this.network.moveTo({ position: this._lastNetworkPosition, scale: 1 });
          console.log(this._nodes);
        }
      });
  }

  private initNetwork() {
    const container = this.graphNetwork.nativeElement;
    this._visCanvasClientRect = this._window.ref.document.querySelector('.grapher__network').getBoundingClientRect();

    console.log(this._visCanvasClientRect);
    this._nodes = [];
    const edges: Edge[] = [];

    const options: Options = {
      physics: {
        enabled: false
      },
      layout: {
        improvedLayout: false,
        randomSeed: 0
      },
      nodes: {
        // scale: can be set based on number of points per scan
        size: 10,
        shape: 'dot',
        font: {
          color: '#fff'
        }
      },
      edges: {
        smooth: false
      },
      interaction: {
        // zoomView: false
      },
      autoResize: true,
    }
    this.network = new Network(container, { nodes: this._nodes, edges }, options);
    this.network.once('afterDrawing', () => {
      console.log(this.getWidthForCanvas(), this.getHeightForCanvas());
      this.network.moveTo({
        scale: 1,
        position: {
          x: 0,
          y: 0
        },
      });
      container.style.width = this.getWidthForCanvas();
    });

    this.network.on('dragEnd', de => {
      console.log(de, this.network.getViewPosition(), this._nodes);
      const node = this._nodes.find(node => node.id === de.nodes[0])
      if (node) {
        node.x += de.event.deltaX;
        node.y += de.event.deltaY;
        this.stepInfo.footerButtons.confirm.isDisabled = false;
      } else {
        this._lastNetworkPosition = this.network.getViewPosition();
      }
    });

    this._lastNetworkPosition = { x: 0, y: 0 };
    this.network.on('zoom', (ev) => {
      const scale = this.network.getScale();
      if (scale <= this._MIN_ZOOM) {
        // console.log(this._lastNetworkPosition, ev, this.network.getViewPosition());
        this.network.moveTo({
          position: this._lastNetworkPosition,
          scale: 1,
        });
      }
    });

  }

  private initGrid() {
    this._d3 = this._window.ref.d3;
    const containerStyle = this._window.ref.document.querySelector('.grapher__grid').getBoundingClientRect();

    this._widthGrid = containerStyle.width;
    this._heightGrid = containerStyle.height;
    let gX = null;
    let gY = null;
    this._currentTransform = null;

    const svg = this._d3.select('.grapher__grid').append('svg');
    const view = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'view');

    if (this._currentTransform) {
      view.attr('transform', this._currentTransform);
    }
    console.log(containerStyle, this._widthGrid, this._heightGrid);
    const xScale = this._d3.scaleLinear().domain([-this._widthGrid, this._widthGrid]).range([0, this._widthGrid]);
    const yScale = this._d3.scaleLinear().domain([-this._heightGrid, this._heightGrid]).range([0, this._heightGrid]);
    const nTicks = 5;

    const xAxis = this._d3
      .axisTop(xScale)
      .ticks(this._widthGrid / this._heightGrid * nTicks)
      .tickSize(-this._heightGrid)
      .tickPadding(-15);

    const yAxis = this._d3
      .axisLeft(yScale)
      .ticks(nTicks)
      .tickSize(-this._widthGrid)
      .tickPadding(-25);

    gX = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'axis axis--x').attr('transform', 'translate(0, 0)').call(xAxis);
    gY = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'axis axis--y').attr('transform', 'translate(0, 0)').call(yAxis);

    this._gridZoom = this._d3
      .zoom()
      .scaleExtent([this._MIN_ZOOM, 3.65])
      .translateExtent([
        [-this._widthGrid, -this._heightGrid],
        [this._widthGrid * 2, this._heightGrid * 2],
      ])
      .on('zoom', (ev) => {
        this._currentTransform = ev.transform;
        view.attr('transform', this._currentTransform);
        gX.call(xAxis.scale(ev.transform.rescaleX(xScale)));
        gY.call(yAxis.scale(ev.transform.rescaleY(yScale)));
      });

    this._d3.select('.grapher').call(this._gridZoom);
  }
```

HTML

```
<div class="grapher">
    <div class="grapher__grid"></div>
    <div class="grapher__network" #graphNetwork></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I answered your question (visjs solution only) on your other post. To do this with a vis/ d3 combo, you should go ahead and post your code that works *"as expected"* apart from the dragging.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie I've added the snippet